# Displaying phone number in US format in iPhone application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, phone-number

In my iPhone app I have a `textfield` to accept phone number. I need to display the number
in US Phone number format. That is like (000) 000-0000. Typically like iPhone Contact phone 
number entry. How can I do this. Any idea will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For auto-formatting, I used [addTarget](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:) in combination with my [PhoneNumberFormatter](http://the-lost-beauty.blogspot.com/2010/01/locale-sensitive-phone-number.html) that [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189804/adam-eberbach) kindly referenced. The implementation is described [here](http://the-lost-beauty.blogspot.com/2010/01/auto-formatting-phone-number.html).

Answer (score 1):

You will get the phone number formatter from

http://the-lost-beauty.blogspot.com/2010/01/locale-sensitive-phone-number.html

Don't forget to use the PhoneNumberFormatter class. This class is also availabel in that blog

Answer (score 0):

Since the user is entering the phone number manually in the text field, you can use the UITextFieldDelegate Method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` to dynamically change the entered phone number by adding '(' before the 1st digit ')' after 3 digits are entered '-' after 6 digits.
(or) after the number entry is done, you can change the displayed format like this:

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
     //resign the keypad and check if 10 numeric digits entered...
     NSRange range;
     range.length = 3;
     range.location = 3;

textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)%@-%@", [textField.text substringToIndex:3], [textField.text substringWithRange:range], [textField.text substringFromIndex:6];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
     //resign the keypad and check if 10 numeric digits entered...
     NSRange range;
     range.length = 3;
     range.location = 3;

textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@-%@", [textField.text substringToIndex:3], [textField.text substringWithRange:range], [textField.text substringFromIndex:6];
}
```